# 1-Year “Skills and Talent” France Visa

Tags: visa, france

I am American and have a PhD in computer science. I would like move to France for 1 year to improve my French and work on a tech-scientific project, completely self-funded.

Is the "Skill and Talent" (Carte Compétences & Talents) the best visa for me? If so, how difficult is it to prove the project contributes to France's scientific goals and get the visa request approved?